# Search by ignore value case checking

Tags: elasticsearch

In my index I have inserted fields without changing the case of values(Upper case or Lower case), like in my elasticsearch document a field `name` contains value `Hello World`. And i have made `name` field as `not_analyzed` for exact match. But in that case, when i search by `hello world` this document don’t returned by elasticsearch, might be due to case sensitivity. I have tried by using `term query` and `match query` but haven't found a luck.

Please suggest, if there is a way.
Thanks

Comment: Can you change the hello world into lower case always in your program??

Comment: @BlackPOP i can do that, but i am looking for any solution supporting to this requirement. And also for vice-versa, like if i have saved in `lower case` word and want to search by `upper case` word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can do this in Elasticsearch is by analyzing the field and using token filters. There is a lowercase token filter available that you should use but this can't really be done on-the-fly like SQL where you wrap the field to be queried against in something like LOWER().

To get the effect you desire I would use something like the [Keyword tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current//analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) with the [Lowercase token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html). If you set this analyzer to be the default analyzer for indexing and searching then your searches will also be case insensitive too.

Comment: yes analyzer is good idea, but i was looking for a feature in search api. But after reading most of the docs, i think it is only possible by using Analyzers. Thanks for the tip.